# Nginx allow clients to omit Host header

Tags: nginx

This question has been asked a few times over the years:

1. [Nginx - Allow requests without a Host header](https://serverfault.com/questions/740597/nginx-allow-requests-without-a-host-header)
2. [Nginx processing requests without a host header](https://serverfault.com/questions/453190/nginx-processing-requests-without-a-host-header)

But I'm hoping the answer may have changed recently. I am working on deprecating a legacy application in which I have no control over the client behavior. Specifically, the clients are making requests via `HTTP/1.1`, but do not include a `Host` header. Nginx follows the RFC in this case and returns a `400` error. I need to override this behavior and accept these requests. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: The standard hasn't changed.

Comment: This seems like something you should be able to easily architect around. What have you tried so far? It might take more layers to your application if you must have this functionality but it's perfectly possible to work around it.

Comment: You might need to change the Nginx source code if you really need to do this. I wonder if another option might be to preprocess the requests with another application - a firewall, HAProxy, or a custom written piece of code.

Comment: I'd simply program a little proxy that modifies the headers for these clients.